# I need to get month and year from dateColumn

Tags: sql, oracle, date

i'm stuck with this part of the query, where I need to get only just month and year from my table.

To put in context, i have tried with "TRUNC_DATE", and Oracle give me back an error like
ORA-00904: "DATE_TRUNC": invalid identifier sql
This piece of query get it from Udacity, but in sql Developer looks like it doesn't work.

When I try search deeper, I find something like convert(char(7), ia.invoice_date(), 120) yearMonth, It still not working and an error came back. ORA-00936: missing expression

I tried a lot of ways but no solutions.

If anyones have an idea o something that could help, I will be grateful.

Here below I paste the fragment of the query for guide help:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(ia.invoice_id) total_de_facturas,
SUM(ia.invoice_amount) monto_total,
convert(char(7), ia.invoice_date(), 120) yearMonth
```

FROM AP.ap_invoices_all ia
GROUP BY ia.vendor_id;

Comment: Do you mean you want the first day of the month, still as a date datatype; or the year and month as (say) numbers; or as a string formatted in a particular way?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a string value in YYYY-MM format - which seems to be your intention from the 120 style and the `char(7)` in the SQL Server-syntax `convert()` call - then you can just use `to_char()` with that format model:

```
to_char(ia.invoice_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yearMonth
```

You don't need to truncate to the first of the month as you're discarding the day part anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You ae mixing Oracle syntax with Postgres (`date_trunc()`) and SQL Server (`convert()`). Many date functions are vendor-specific, so you learn the relevant syntax for your database.

In Oracle, you would use `trunc()` to truncate a date to the first day of the month:

```
trunc(ia.invoice_date, 'mm')
```

Comment: Thanks, i will consider it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the EXTRACT function, try these out to test how it works and use it in your query -

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE '2020-03-07') FROM DUAL;
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '2020-03-07') FROM DUAL;
```